# Is my solution to this SQL problem from an interview correct?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am  new to SQL (just completed a course on Edx) and had this interview question before I knew anything and thought I'd give it a shot now. Wondering if my solution is correct. Thank you!

**Problem**

Given the following two database tables, team and player (with corresponding database columns provided in rows 8-12 below), write a SQL statement that would return a list of names of the top 10 teams sorted from the tallest average player to the shortest. Assume that player height is stored as an integer representing number of inches.

***team***

```
id
league
name
division
```

***player***

```
id
name
height
weight
team_id
```

**Solution**

```
SELECT TOP 10 T.Team, P.Name
FROM Team AS T
JOIN Player AS P on T.id = P.team_id
ORDER BY height DESC;
```

Comment: What is the *tallest average player*? Do you want a record per team, sorted by avereage player height, or maby by maximum player height? Or maybe you want a record per team *and* player? Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Comment: That query will just give the 10 tallest players across all teams.

Comment: You need a query that returns one row per team, not one row per player.

Comment: That problem statement is pretty poorly phrased. It's also doesn't make sense: There isn't necessarily "the" top 10--what if multiple teams are tied for 10th & some higher-numbered places?

Answer (score 0):

The teams sorted by average height of players

```
sql server:

select top 10 T.name, avg(height) as AvgHeight
from team t inner join Player p on T.id = P.team_id
group by T.name
order by 2 desc

Postgres


select T.name, avg(height) as AvgHeight
from team t inner join Player p on T.id = P.team_id
group by T.name
order by 2 desc limit 10;
```

Comment: Should be `order by desc`. And it is better to group by `id`, which is (supposed to be) unique, rather than `name`, that may be not unique.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir, i figured as it was team name, they would be unique but you do have a point, with id, its a more generic solution

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your solution is not correct - that would essentially provide you a list of players with the greatest height. So, if the two tallest players in the database were on the same team, that team name would appear twice.

Here's how I would write the query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 T.[name] as [Team Name], AVG(P.[height]) as [Average Height]
FROM team T
INNER JOIN player P on (T.[id] = P.[team_id])
GROUP BY T.[name]
ORDER BY AVG(P.[height]) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you - I realized I completely misread the problem and this makes total sense. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very important lesson! In IT, you reallyneed to haev good communication to capture the problem correctly. You can write the best SQL in the world but if you can't understand or describe requirements, you will not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement asks you to select out the names of the teams, not to select out the height. You need to order the team names by average player height, and you can do this without selecting the average height as part of the final result set by using `GROUP BY` along with the `AVG()` function.

```
SELECT TOP 10 T.name FROM team T
INNER JOIN player P
ON T.id = P.team_id
GROUP BY T.id
ORDER BY AVG(P.height) DESC
```